# Redirecting Command output to file

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-10.04, redirection

This seems so simple when doing it from command line but I'm not able to accomplish it inside a script. I am trying to put output of following command into a text file:

```
CMD= mysql -uroot -psecret -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;'
FIL=~/replication-`date +%F`.txt
MAILTEXT=~/mailtext.txt

touch $FIL
$CMD > $FIL
```

Where `FIL` is a variable that contains path of the file to which to output command. I am running this command in a shell script from where I want to email contents of `$FIL` as attachment using `mutt`. But I am always getting 0 byte file. Also if I examine in directory the file is of 0 byte length.

Comment: what if you do (mysql -uroot -psecret -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;') > $FILE

Comment: @barlop I have updated question with actual script.

Comment: Your first assignment to `CMD` will not work, get rid of the space after `=` and surround the values with double quotes - `sh` is extremely odd in its treatment of whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't with the redirection, it's with how you're storing the command in a variable.  First, you can't put a space after the `=` in the assignment; with the space there, it sets CMD blank and runs the command `mysql -uroot -psecret -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;'`.  If you just remove the space, it'll set CMD to "mysql" and try to run the command `-uroot -psecret -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;'`.  So, as @Michał Šrajer suggested, you could wrap it in double-quotes so the whole thing gets assigned to CMD.  But it still doesn't work, because when `$CMD` is expanded, it doesn't pay attention to the quotes inside it.  When bash parses a command line, it parses quotes before it expands variables, so putting quotes inside a variable doesn't do anything useful.

Storing a command in a variable is tricky.  [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) has some good discussion and options.  In this case, the options that look relevant to me are:

1. Don't put the command in a variable in the first place.  If there's no good reason for it, don't do it:

   ```
   FIL=~/replication-`date +%F`.txt
   MAILTEXT=~/mailtext.txt

   touch $FIL
   mysql -uroot -psecret -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;' > $FIL
   ```
2. If you must put the command in a variable, use an array instead of a simple text variable.  In this case, the quotes will be parsed when the variable in created, and if you use it as `"${varname[@]}"` the breaks between "words" will be preserved:

   ```
   CMD=(mysql -uroot -psecret -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;')
   FIL=~/replication-`date +%F`.txt
   MAILTEXT=~/mailtext.txt

   touch $FIL
   "${CMD[@]}" > $FIL
   ```

Comment: thanks, first one worked but second one gave this error: ` Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: Is this script being run by bash, or some other shell?  Arrays are an extension, so more basic shells won't support them. Make sure the shebang (first line of the script) is `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
CMD= mysql -uroot -psecret -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;'
```

to:

```
CMD="mysql -uroot -psecret -e 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a similar script which does work:

```
FIL=~/test.txt
CMD="hostname"
touch $FIL
$CMD > $FIL
```

Did you try without the redirection first, to see whether the outputs get generated at all?